# El inicializador de colecciones tiene argumentos no validos

Tags: c#

Buenas estoy aprendiendo C# aquí el motivo de mi pregunta ya que al mirar en la documentación no llego a comprenderlo, a ver si me podrían decir el motivo de porque tiene argumentos no válidos.

es un ejercicio de herencias para crear una tienda donde puedas comprar, obviamente no esta terminado,
la cosa es  porque no son argumentos validos si son los mismos que tengo en las clases o como tienen que ser los argumentos para que sean validos, el error esta en la clase estática al crear la lista.

no hace falta que me digan la solución mas bien el porque no son valido.

les dejo todo el código para que puedan ojearlo, seguramente tenga algunas cosillas mal o que no tengan  que estar ya que soy novato en esto.

gracias un saludo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using static ejerciciopracticotema3.Program;

namespace ejerciciopracticotema3
{
    public class Program
    {
        
        public DefinicionGeneral[] inventarioTienda;       
        public float aPagar
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public float dinero
        {
            get; set;
        }
        


        public class Naranjas : DefinicionGeneral, IAPeso
        {
            public float precioPorKg
            {
              get; set;
            }
            public bool aPeso
            {
                get; set;
            }

            
            public void SetVarNaranjas()
            {

                precioPorKg = 0.75f;
                aPeso = true;
                SetNameId("Naranjas", precioPorKg,0.75f);

            }
            public Naranjas(float x, bool b) { precioPorKg = x; aPeso = true; }

        }

        public class Berenjenas : DefinicionGeneral, IAPeso
        {
            
            
            public float precioPorKg
            {
                get; set;
            }
            public bool aPeso
            {
                get; set;
            }

            public void SetVarBerenjenas()
            {
                precioPorKg = 0.85f;
                aPeso = true;
                SetNameId("Berenjenas", precioPorKg, 0.85f);
            }

            public Berenjenas(float x, bool b) { precioPorKg = x; aPeso = true; }

        }

        public class Pelota : DefinicionGeneral,IUnitario
        {
            public float precioPorItem
            {

                get; set;

            }
            public int cantidad
            {

                get; set;


            }
            public void SetVarPelota()
            {
                precioPorItem = 1.60f;
                cantidad = 1;
                SetNameId("Pelota", 1, 1.60f);

            }

            public Pelota(float x, int c) { precioPorItem = x; cantidad = c; }

        }

        public class Yatekomo : DefinicionGeneral, IUnitario
        {

            public float precioPorItem
            {
                get; set;
            }

            public int cantidad
            {
                get; set;
            }

            public void SetVarYatekomo()
            {
                precioPorItem = 2.20f;
                cantidad = 1;
                SetNameId("Yatekomo", 1, 2.20f);

            }
           public Yatekomo(float x, int c) { precioPorItem = x; cantidad = c; }
        }


         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            Program p = new Program();

            //p.inventarioTienda = Inventario.inventarioDeLaTienda;

            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenidos a tiendas paqui");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("tenemos todo esto disponible en tienda: ");
            foreach(DefinicionGeneral dG in p.inventarioTienda)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( dG.name + " Tiene un precio de "+ dG.precio);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Que cantidad de dinero tienes disponible? ");
            p.dinero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Perfecto tienes disponible para gastar: " + p.dinero + " Euros");
            
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("elige que Kg deseas comprar: ");

            

        }
    }
    public static class Inventario
    {



        //public static string[] inventarioDeLaTienda;
        
        public static void InventarioTienda()
        {
            List<DefinicionGeneral> inventarioDeLaTienda = new List<Program>()
             {
             //error del inicializador de colecciones tiene algunos argumentos no válidos 
                new Naranjas(0.75f, true), 
                new Berenjenas(0.85f, true),
                new Pelota(1.60f, 1),
                new Yatekomo(2.20f, 1),
             }; 
            
        }

        
    


    }
    
    public abstract class DefinicionGeneral
    {

         

        public string name { get; set; } 

        public float iD { get; set; } 
        public float precio;

        public virtual void SetNameId(string s, float i, float ip)
        {
            
            name = s;
            iD = i;
            precio = ip;

        }

    }
    interface IAPeso
    {

        public float precioPorKg
        {
            get; set;
        }
        
        public bool aPeso
        {
            get; set;
        }

    }
    interface IUnitario
    {
        public float precioPorItem
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public int cantidad
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberias revisar esta linea de código `public Naranjas(float x, bool b) { precioPorKg = x; aPeso = true; }` así tu variable `aPeso` siempre tomara valor `True` deberia ser de la siguente manera: `public Naranjas(float x, bool b) { precioPorKg = x; aPeso = b; }`. Lo mismo sucede en esta  `public Berenjenas(float x, bool b) { precioPorKg = x; aPeso = true; }` que deberia quedar así `public Berenjenas(float x, bool b) { precioPorKg = x; aPeso = b; }`.

Comment: cierto le echare un ojo gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola aqui esta tu error tenias List Program y tu Naranjas, Pelota, etc.. no son Program.

Asi deberia de ser

```
 List<DefinicionGeneral> inventarioDeLaTienda = new List<DefinicionGeneral>()
             {
             //error del inicializador de colecciones tiene algunos argumentos no válidos 
                new Naranjas(0.75f, true),
                new Berenjenas(0.85f, true),
                new Pelota(1.60f, 1),
                new Yatekomo(2.20f, 1),
             };
```

Comment: joder vaya tontería era y que no me haya dado cuenta después de varias horas mirando el código, mil gracias un saludo!!